# applying CRUD operations on ontology from a semantic web application

Tags: crud, jena, ontology, semantic-web

I am trying to develop a semantic web application using:

1. Java
2. Eclipse IDE
3. Protégé Ontology Editor
4. Jena Semantic Web Framework
5. Pellet Reasoner

like in [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7092025)
but I think this will only work with "select" statements.
is there anyway to develop a semantic web application can offer full CRUD operations on my ontology? should I use some triple store to host the ontology instead of working with Jena?

Comment: Just fyi, the article you linked to isn't accessible.

Comment: hopefully fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question with specific details since it is so general, but basically, ontologies are graphs just like any other graph.

So if your application supports [SPARQL Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) queries, there should be no problem in updating your ontology through your application directly.

---

A quick word of warning though. The ontology is the closest thing to a "model" that semantic applications use. If you plan to change your ontology on-the-go, you have to make sure that the rest of your knowledge base stays consistent with your changes.

For instance, if you delete a class from the ontology, then you have to make sure that you have no instances of that class in the knowledge base. Otherwise, your knowledge base will contain triples referring to classes or predicates that might not exist anymore.

Comment: the desired update is to update the individuals "the instances" of ontology classes not the classes themselves, like in relational databases, we update and delete records not tables.
so I think knowledge base stays consistent with changes, right?

Comment: Ah, so in that case, you're updating the knowledge base, not the ontology. Well, then, any application supporting SPARQL Update queries will do the trick.

Comment: I ended up with this framework (https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/stable/user_guide/Getting-Started.html)
and this github (https://gist.github.com/gra-moore/2471946).
as you understand what I need, do you think I am on the right way or do you recommend something else?

Comment: Yes. In particular [this part](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/stable/user_guide/Updating-With-SPARQL.html) of the dotNetRDF documentation seems relevant to what you are trying to do.